# Mysterious property of the curvature of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I know that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can define the curvature of a parametrized curve $\textbf{x}(t)=\bigl( x(t), y(t)\bigr)$ as
$$ \kappa(t) = \dfrac{\text{det}(\textbf{x}',\textbf{x}'')}{||\textbf{x}'||^3}.$$
If I use a change of parameter $\overline{t}=\phi(t)$ we can reparametrize the curvature
$$ \boxed{\overline{\kappa}(\overline{t}) =\kappa(t)}\tag{1}.$$
Equation (1) is the definition of a **scalar**. The curvature is a scalar magnitude.

> My question is: Why is the meaning of the next equation, very similar
>   to equation (1)? In particular, what functions verify the next
>   equations? $$ \overline{\kappa}(t)=\kappa(t) .\tag{2}$$
>   Perhaps it's related to a geodesic. My teacher says that the solution is in a General Relativity book but it can be answered without any physic concept.

Comment: Presumably $\bar{\kappa}(t) = \kappa(t)$ refers to a curvature being invariant under reparametrization, i.e., to a curve having _constant curvature_, an arc of a circle or a line segment.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewD.Hwang, the physic concept could be the volume element? $$ \sqrt{g} \text{ d}u^1 \text{ d}u^2$$ where $g$ is the determinant of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: It turns out that curvature of a curve is an "extrinsic" quantity; it _cannot_ be detected by measurements within the curve. Since the volume form is intrinsic, the curvature condition cannot be expressed in terms of the volume  element. (Separately, the volume element for a curve is a "$1$-form", of the type $\|\mathbf{x}'(t)\|\, dt$.) Perhaps the physical concept is "uniform bending".

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: I don't understand. Being invariant under reparametrization should be the original equation $\bar\kappa(\bar t) = \kappa(t)$.  So, yes, if $\bar t$ and $t$ line up for arbitrary reparametrizations, than curvature must be constant.

Comment: @Ted: Not sure what you don't understand...? :) My second comment was in response to (and disaffirming) OP's guess that the physical concept underlying the condition $\bar{\kappa}(t) = \kappa(t)$ has to do with the volume element.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Andy, I was responding to your very first comment. I'm just emphasizing the significance of the dropping of the $\bar t$ for $t$.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326473/2451